# bash script will not launch graphical application

Tags: python, shell

I made an application with Python and Kivy. I have a shell script that launches it:

```
#!/bin/bash

PyPath=/usr/bin/python

source $HOME/.bashrc
$PyPath ./Source/principal.py 
sleep 2
```

When I run this file from the terminal, everything works. The problem is I also need that it runs when I double click it on a filemanager (Nautilus, PCManFM, Thunar, etc) and it doesn't. When I double click it, the manager runs something in background (the mouse icon changes to working) and then nothing.

Could anyone help me a bit here?

Thanks!

-Ricardo

Comment: Do you want it to open a terminal window with the code running?

Comment: try changing the cmd invocation to `$PyPath ./Source/principal.py &` (run it in the background) .Good luck.

Comment: @rosh i want the app to open! if i doubleclick, nothing happens

Comment: @shellter it didnt work.

Comment: OK, how about `$PyPath /full/path/to/Source/principal.ph` ? Good luck.